# Stanford CoreNLP output is very slow in Python

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

I'm using NLTK's StanfordDependencyParser to generate dependency trees. Here is the code

```py
cpath = "path to stanford-corenlp-4.2.0-models-english.jar" + os.pathsep + "path to stanford-parser.jar"

if cpath not in os.environ['CLASSPATH']:
     os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = cpath + os.pathsep + os.environ['CLASSPATH']

# TODO: DEPRECATED
# self.dependency_parser_instance_corenlp = StanfordDependencyParser(path_to_models_jar="path to stanford-corenlp-4.2.0-models-english.jar", encoding='utf8')

dependencies = [list(parse.triples()) for parse in self.dependency_parser_instance_corenlp.raw_parse(query)]

# Encode every string in tree to utf8 so string matching will work
for dependency in dependencies[0]:
    dependency[0][0].encode('utf-8')
    dependency[0][1].encode('utf-8')
    dependency[1].encode('utf-8')
    dependency[2][0].encode('utf-8')
    dependency[2][1].encode('utf-8')
```

For a sentence with 10 words, it takes around 1.5 seconds to generate the output. Is this expected? Can you please steps to improve speed?
I've already tried using SR parser and removing all the extra folders(like coref, lexparser, ner, tagger) from the models JAR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the (old NLTK implementation) `StanfordDependencyParser` is very slow. You should not use it. You should use the classes and methods in the [nltk.parse.corenlp](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.parse.html#module-nltk.parse.corenlp) module, which are *much* faster.

For more info, see the notes in the [CoreNLP documentation](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/other-languages.html#python) or [this tutorial](https://www.districtdatalabs.com/syntax-parsing-with-corenlp-and-nltk).

Comment: I used the NLTK's CoreNLPDependencyParser parser and it reduced the time by more than a second. Now, my query takes about 0.4 seconds to execute. This is great, thank you!!